# Excel VBA script to count the number of values in column A that are less than the values in Column B same row

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CompareValues()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cellA As Object
    Dim cellB As Object
    Dim count As Integer

    Set rng = Selection
    For Each cell In rng
        'test if value in column A is less than in column B
        If cellA.Value < cellB.Value Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Basically I have a spreadsheet with 50+ columns that each have 350 rows with mostly numeric values (the values will either be a number or NA if a result wasn't available). I want to be able to generate a count at the bottom of each column that tells me how many of the values in a column are less than the equivalent values in the previous column. So if B3 < A3 the count would go up. But if B3=A3 or B3 > A3 then it wouldn't iterate the count. I know I need to loop through each value and compare it to the value in the same row in the previous column but I'm pretty lost on how to actually do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Your title contradicts your body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution just using formulas. At the bottom of each column, for example on `B351` you would use the array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A350<=B1:B350,1,0))
```

Note that this is inputted by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`. Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I I was trying to accomplish it with COUNTIF and couldn't figure out how to make it work so I kind of assumed I had to use a vbscript. I've never been so glad to be wrong. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. I'm sure you could have done it as well with `COUNTIFS` which would be more efficient than array formulas. But if this meets your needs I'm glad regardless :)